# Checking size of an array through function

Tags: c++, arrays

When I want to know the size of an array I do the following :

```
int array[30];
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
     array[i] = i+1; //Fill list
const int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

But when I pass the array as argument in a function I will have a pointer in the function.

```
int size( int array[] )
{
    return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); //Doesn't work anymore
}
```

This obviously doesn't work. But how do I get the size of that array in a function without taking another parameter for the size?

Comment: @chris this is also tagged for c and c doesn't offer std::array :p

Comment: You can't using pure C. The int array[] in the method decays to a pointer - so there's no way to do it like that.

Comment: Using c-type arrays, you can't. You simply don't have the ability to know the length of an array after it's been passed, because 1) how easy it is to go beyond the bounds and 2) only the pointer to the first element is passed. The only exception is null-terminated strings.

Comment: @Davlog, Well, if it's tagged C++, I assume the OP uses C++. That's my rule, and if my C++ suggestions aren't appreciated, the tag should be removed. If they are, the C tag should be removed.

Comment: You do it differently in C and in C++. Pick your language.

Comment: function parameter declarations are different then  formal declarations so `int size( int array[] )` is same as `int size( int*  array)` hence `sizeof(array)` == `sizeof(pointer)` and `sizeof(array[0]` == `sizeof(int)`

Comment: @Davlog, in a question like this, you shouldn't tag both `C` and `C++`.  The answers are quite different (because C++ allows a much easier answer).  If you're using a C++ compiler, please delete the `C` tag.  If not, delete `C++`.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid C and C++ are in some ways really similar. There are always solutions for both, C and C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do I get the size of that array in a function without taking
>   another parameter for the size?

You don't.  The size of the array has to be *somewhere* visible to the compiler.  Otherwise all you'll be able to pass is a pointer to the first element in the array.

However, you can use a `template` for the size, and make this a little more magical and seamless:

```
template <size_t N>  int size (const int (&ary)[N])
{
    assert (N == (sizeof(ary) / sizeof (ary[0])));
    return N;
}
```

And further templatizing the type of elements, so this works with arrays of anything:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>  int size (const T (&ary)[N])
{
    assert (N == (sizeof(ary) / sizeof (ary[0])));
    return N;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to get the size of the array using function templates:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size(const T (&)[N] ) // omit constexpr if no C++11 support
{
  return N
}
```

then

```
for(int i = 0; i < size(array); i++) { .... }
```

but you could simplify things by using an `std::array` (or `std::tr1::array` or `boost::array` if you don't have C++11) and using it's `size()` method.

Answer (score 1):

In C, arrays in function parameters behave very strangely.  Frankly, I think the language was very badly designed here.

```
void foo(int data[10]) {
    int *p;
    int a[10];
}
```

`sizeof(p)` will probably be 4 (or maybe 8). And `sizeof(a)` will be 40 (or 80).

So what do you think `sizeof(data)` will be?  If you guessed 40 (or 80), you're wrong.  Instead, its size is the same as `sizeof(p)`.

If a C compiler see a `[` immediately after the name of a parameter, it removes it and replaces it with a pointer, and `data[10]` becomes `*data`.  (This is different from the decaying behaviour we get with arrays elsewhere, when a parameter, arrays are dealt with more drastically).

In fact, the following will compile despite the different sized arrays:

```
int foo(int data[10]);
int main() {
    int hugearray[1000];
    foo(hugearray); // this compiles!
}
```

The C compiler doesn't respect, in any way, the size of array parameters.  I believe that compilers should issue a warning on any array parameters, and encourage us to use the `*` directly.  I might allow `[]`, but certainly not `[10]` given that it's ignored by the compiler.

If you want your C compiler to respect the size of arrays, you should pass the address of the array.

```
int foo(int (*data)[10]);
int main() {
    int smallarray[10];
    foo(&smallarray); // OK
    int hugearray[1000];
    foo(&hugearray); // error, as desired
}
```

Returning to the original question, parameter arrays know nothing about their size.

Answer (score 0):

In C you can't find the size of array by passing array beginning address to function.

For example You have made function call

```
size(array); // You are calling function  by passing address of array beginning element 

int size( int array[] ) // this is same as int size(int *array)
{
    return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); //Doesn't work anymore
}
```

Here `sizeof(array)` will give you the size of pointer. that is architecture dependent.

And if you pass character array instead of int array and that too if the character array was nulterminated then You can use `strlen()`.This is the only way we can find the size of array.

`strlen()` counts till nul occurrence, You can use this trick However allocate memory for one more element to your array or declare your array with MAX_SIZE+1 .When ever if you store array elements of size n then  store a known value inside array[n] and while finding size check against that value like `strlen()` Checks for Nul character.

Comment: You just repeat what OP said: "But when I pass the array as argument in a function I will have a pointer in the function. This obviously doesn't work."

Comment: @kotlomoy thanks for pointing this. added some more info in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Macro

```
int findSize(int array[])
{
//This will not return size off array,it will just get starting address array and no information about boundaries

    return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

}
//But we can define a Macro for this

#define FIND_ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

int main()
{

    int SampleArray[30];

    printf("\nSize =%d ",sizeof(SampleArray) / sizeof(SampleArray[0]));
    printf("\nSize from Function =%d ",findSize(SampleArray));
    printf("\nSize from Macro =%d ",FIND_ARRAY_SIZE(SampleArray));
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```